# Extracting rows between 2 dates using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
id    date       temp       prcp
1   2015-01-01  -27.18      0
1   2015-01-02  -25.9       1.03
1   2015-01-03  -17.89      9.44
1   2015-01-04  -17.89      9.44
1   2015-01-05  -17.89      9.44

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id=1 and date between '2015-01-03' and '2015-01-05'
```

How do I fix the SQL query above? I am trying to extract all rows between the 2 dates `'2015-01-03' and '2015-01-05'`

Comment: Did you mean `date >= '2015-01-03' and date <= '2015-01-05'`?

Comment: that works! If you put it as answer, I will accept. Also any ideas why between does not work?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work. Does your underlying sql support `between`?

Comment: hmm, I think so, I am using postgreSQL

Comment: I saw an example of a complex query where they put the `BETWEEN` expression in parens, to separate `BETWEEN ... AND` from logical `AND`: `SELECT ... WHERE (x BETWEEN v1 AND v2) AND other stuff`. Maybe put your between in parens?

Comment: `date >= '2015-01-03' and date <= '2015-01-05'` is exactly the same thing as `date between '2015-01-03' and '2015-01-05'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean date >= '2015-01-03' and date <= '2015-01-05'?

Comment: Which is exactly the same as `date between '2015-01-03'  and '2015-01-05'`

Answer (score 2):

I think "date" as the column name is a bad idea. 
Try quoting them with double quote.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html#KEYWORDS-TABLE   "In Table C-1 in the column for PostgreSQL ... If not so marked, a reserved key word is only allowed as an "AS" column label name."   and date is not marked.